# Ubuntu 20.04 no longer boots on Dell XPS 2019: grub sees the vnme disk, but the kernel doesn't

Tags: boot, 20.04, nvme

The machine is configured in dual boot Windows 10/Ubuntu 20.04.

Windows boots fine, but attempting to boot Ubuntu throws me to the `(initramfs)` prompt because it can't find the root partition, which it looks up by UUID.

If I go to grub's command line and do `ls (hd0,7)` it sees the ext* filesystem, and it has the correct UUID. I can load the kernel & initrd with

```
set root=(hd0,7)
linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/nvme0n1p7
initrd /boot/initrd.img
```

But when I do `boot`, I end up in the `initramfs` prompt again. This happens both with `vmlinuz` and `vmlinuz.old` (and the corresponding `initrd.img`).

I tried booting off an USB key, and that works, but there are no `/dev/nvme*` devices.

This happens regardless of the secure boot setting in the BIOS.

Any ideas what may be going on?

Comment: Addendum: the disk is set to RAID mode in the BIOS, and it used to work until recently, I don't know *what* changed.

Answer (score 1):

Switching the disk mode to AHCI fixed the issue.

It required some recklessness, on my part, as switching modes brings up a scary message about this change potentially requiring a reinstall.

I have no idea how my machine got into that state, so I decided to blame Windows.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-)

Comment: Of course, once I did that, Windows refused to boot.

Fortunately, there's a not particularly intuitive way to get Windows to switch to AHCI: https://support.thinkcritical.com/kb/articles/switch-windows-10-from-raid-ide-to-ahci